# Not able to get Top command output with full command path by crontab

Tags: linux, shell, cron, command

I made a shell script to get a full output of a top command with full absolute path of a command running and sort bu %cpu.

/!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/top -o +%CPU -c -n 1 -b >> /dba/output.log

This gave me output which i want if i run manually but if i schedule this in the crontab its not gave me full path of a command which taking highest CPU

Can anybody help me in this

I am expecting to get a full path of a command running and taking CPU  by TOP command but script not giving me proper path of the command if i am running this by crontab

Answer (score 0):

When you run it on the CLI it uses your personal login. When it runs scheduled it runs with a different account and therefore works different. If it's a test environment run the instance under your login to test if it's a rights issue or if it's production contact admins.

Comment: I login with root user still not get anyoutput

Comment: A cronjob runs under the service account, not the user you're logged in as.

Comment: So let me know what command or script I suppose to use…. It would be so helpfull

Comment: Be carefull! Involves downtime and serious risks. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/changing-mysql-user.html

Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: Thanks dear but not help me in my case because i want  to get a output of linux top command batch mode in a log file by schedule the shell script in crontab  but  in output absolute path of every command is missing in my output file  and